# HEROKU - can't deploy java app with jdk11

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku

Current approach:

As suggested there https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support, I've created a system.properties file in a root folder, with java.runtime.version=11 
Still jdk 8 is installed as seen in the picture

[image]

JAVA_HOME

[image: java_home and path]

Not sure what am I missing here?

Comment: have you added the `system.properties` file to Git with `git add`?

Comment: yes, I did it. I've rebooted and somehow it works now

Comment: @codefinger: I have added the system.properties file, but still it is installing java 8..
Schroedinger: please let me know the steps you have tried to resolve it..

Comment: make sure the `system.properties` is committed to Git

Answer (score 1):

For any one who is still facing this issue. My problem was i was on a different branch so i had to run `git push heroku yourbranch:master`.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using Docker. It will easier to configure and you will be able to run it locally and it should behave the same as in Heroku. Moreover Heroku has good support for deploying using Docker.
You can check out deploying process here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker

Process of building docker image will be different depending on what build system you use.